# Site in Laravel Valet can't find Memcache, but I see the process running—what now?

Tags: php, memcached, homebrew, laravel-valet

I have a local WP site that depends on Memcached. The readme says "Use memcached and the PECL memcache extension to provide a backing store for the WordPress object cache."

As a far as I can tell, my config meets those requirements. But when I attempt to access the application, I get:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcache' not found in. . .`

I'm running php 7.3 installed via Homebrew, and Memcached 3.1.3, installed via PECL. Memcached 3.1.3 says it's compatible with php 7.3, and I followed [these instructions](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/memcached-and-valet-203) to add Memcache as an extension to my php server. If I start php via Homebrew, I can see the Memcache process when I run `ps -ef | grep -i memcached`, and the config appears when I run `php --info | grep memcached\\.` But, I can't connect to Memcached through my Valet app or through Telnet.

If I run Memcached through Homebrew, I get a different version, `1.5.13`, which I think predates php 7.3. As I understand Homebrew only installs stable releases. When the Homebrew Memcache is running I can connect via Telnet, but not through the Valet app.

What's different about the Homebrew install of Memcached? I assume Homebrew must somehow make Memcache externally accessible but I don't know what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

```
brew install libmemcached
brew install pkg-config
pecl install memcached
```

Push Enter to all question

Then:

```
cd /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
sudo vim php.ini
[memcached]
extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.5/pecl/20180731/memcached.so
```

Replace path parts accordingly to your system

Finally:

```
brew services restart php
php -m
```

Comment: There was an error for zlib dir. I have passed that zlib path when while installing the`pecl install memcached` installation done successfully. Thanks your solution worked.